# How to initialise CUDA Thrust vector without implicitly invoking 'copy'?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, thrust

I have a pointer `int *h_a` which references a large number `N` of data points (on host) that I want to copy to device. So I do:

```
thrust::host_vector<int> ht_a(h_a, h_a + N);
thrust::device_vector<int> dt_a = ht_a;
```

However, creating `ht_a` seems to implictly *copy* `h_a` rather than reference it, which is inefficient as I don't need another copy of `h_a`.

I just want to create `ht_a` such that `&ht_a[0]` points to `h_a[0]` - how to do this?

Many thanks.

*Alternatively, as I'm not actually doing anything with `ht_a` other than copying to device memory, I'd be interested to know if we can go directly between `int*` and `thrust::device_vector<int>`.*

Comment: Yes, you can initialize `device_vector` directly from two `int*`s just like you did with `host_vector` in your example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edited code to also show how to copy back from device to host:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>

int main() {

 int N = 10;
 int *h_a;
 int *h_b;
 h_a = (int *)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
 h_b = (int *)malloc(N*sizeof(int));
 for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
   h_a[i] = i;
   h_b[i] = 0;
   }

 thrust::device_vector<int> dt_a(h_a, h_a + N);

 thrust::copy(dt_a.begin(), dt_a.end(), h_b);

 for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
   printf("h_b[%d] = %d\n", i, h_b[i]);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to do I get back from `dt_a` to `h_a` (i.e. `thrust::device_vector<int>` to host `int*`)?

Comment: Thanks. Are these operations synchronous?

Comment: Yes, all of the thrust copy operations I've shown above are synchronous (both the implicit copy on creation of `dt_a` and the explicit `thrust::copy` without an execution policy). Meaning control is not returned to the host thread until the function is complete

Comment: `malloc` in C++ code?? Even in 2013 `new` was the way to go.. (nowadays it would be `std::unique_ptr`.) memory leak btw.